# How to obtain an evidence of teacher effectiveness when I never was evaluated?

Tags: application, teaching

I have spent my career working in the field and have recently been approached to teach some classes that are specific to what I do. I have been asked to turn in an “evidence of teacher effectiveness.” I do not have any evaluations or proof that I would be a good teacher. I have guest-lectured a few times and can probably get a few quotes about how I did. Apart from this, what could I use to fulfill this requirement?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What level are you teaching? University?

Comment: Course evaluations would be nice but I don't think that's the only or best way to answer the question.  It's more about what you are doing or what do you plan to do to be an effective teacher.  Are you just going to stand in front of the room and talk or are you further knowledge via reading and other assignments, testing, study sessions, guest lectures, videos, optional homework, etc., etc.  

Think of this question in that context.  What is the "whole picture" of you as a teacher?

Comment: Were you ever invited to guest lecture for the same person/organization a second time? Being invited back would be evidence that at least the person giving the invitation found you effective.

Answer (score 3):

If someone is asking you to teach classes before you've had any experience doing it, then I'm going to guess that they don't expect you to produce a full dossier.  In that case, letters of recommendation from the people that invited you to give guest lectures, or people who saw them, might be sufficient.  You might get some clarification on what's expected by asking the person who's asking you to teach the classes.

Answer (score 0):

Never a teacher, but as a recent student, here are my suggestions:

- Record one of your lectures of both the speaker (you) and the audience (students). If you can command the attention of your students, then I can argue that this is an indicator of "effectiveness".
- Polls and opinions, much like how the Political Campaigns take polls of their constituents, you can take straw polls from your students on how well you did. "What was unclear?", "What should I focus on in the next class?" Etc.
- Recommendations from senior instructors, I am not sure if this is viable from the other side of the podium, but certainly if it applies, then it is another means.